# Ubuntu 12.10 Unity Dash transparency problem

Tags: unity, graphics, unity-dash, 12.10, transparency

I have just upgraded my Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 and there is following problem.
When I press super button to show Unity Dash I get wrong background image behind the dash box. Especially I can see part of the bottom of the screen. Also when I set transparency to top panel the background behind is not correct.

Here is an example with Mc Duck picture:
[Unity Mc Duck example](http://s11.postimage.org/kaluqju9f/Screenshot_from_2012_10_20_23_36_28.png)

Do you have any ideas whats wrong?

My system preferences:
Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit
Intel® Pentium(R) CPU G840 @ 2.80GHz × 2
GeForce GTS 450/PCIe/SSE2

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed a similar problem on my 12.04 today, after an upgrade. Here's how I fixed it:

I don't know if you're aware, the DASH's background colour can be customized to an extent. If you have CompizConfig Settings Manager, Open it, then go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Experimental.There you will find a setting called 'Dash Blur'. It can be set to one of three values:

- No Blur;
- Static Blur;
- Active Blur

The default is Active Blur. I won't be explaining here what's what, but it turns out that the actual values of these three options got mixed up. So why don't you open your CCSM and play a bit with these values? I've managed to fix my problem by selecting 'No Blur'.

Comment: It works, but with option "Active Blur". Thank you Томица!

Comment: Glad I could help :)